# I can't see my whole activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

In the Android Studio, when i'm developing the app, I can't see the whole activity... I just see the components that i added to the layout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/le5Gl.png

I shold see something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnoIx.png

I uninstall and install the IDE and nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your first image, click on the little eye icon on the top left hand of the image.
Select show layout decorations

Hope it helps!

[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNjaf.png)